# Why does the object spin around a random dot, instead of its own axis?

Tags: objects, origin

[image]

My donut just started moving based on this dot and I have no idea how to fix it.

How can fix this so the donut isn't moving around the dot?

Answer (score 7):

It's not a random dot, it's the object origin. To bring it back to the object geometry, right click > *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry*